# display text within a box using css

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is set inside a container as a background image, over it i am trying to place a box in which i am supposed to write text, however my problem is that if the text is too long then it increases the height of the box and it displays out of the background image.
I want the box and the text within it to be always within the image area no matter how long the text is and the whole text should be visible  (i.e the image should adjust itself in a way that the box and its text should always be inside it and would be great if it is responsive also)

```css
.container2 {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.newtestiimg2 {
  background-image: url("../testimonial/page.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.comment01 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -600px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="newtestiimg2"></div>
  <div class="comment01">
    <div class="service-wrapper01"> What is fosho ? </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum .... long text continues</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an error in Your HTML. First `<p>` tag is not closed.

Comment: A certain amount of text takes up a certain amount of area. There are two things you can do: shrink the font size of the text (which you can only do to a point before it becomes illegible) or allow it to `overflow:auto;`, which will cause some of your text to be hidden.

Comment: for overflowing text you can put vertical scrollbar,

Comment: use `overflow` properties.

Comment: You'd have to set the box width to match your picture. For responsiveness think about getting rid of the image if it can be created with CSS or use a vector. It really depends on the image you use when it comes to responsiveness.

Comment: Are you able to provide an absolute link for that image?

Comment: @roy, The problem is with the div "newtestiimg2", you need to close the div after this div "comment01".

Comment: can you show your expected output as image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set fixed height and width and use overflow in CSS.

Example:

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Check this JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g8mv9eq4/

**UPDATE #1**: https://jsfiddle.net/g8mv9eq4/1/

Comment: if i do so then the complete css is getting disturbed

Comment: The rule shouldn't be targeting all DIV elements.

Comment: @roy Check the link I have added to my answer.

Comment: @chimos Still... this is an example ;)

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos I downvoted because I found your answer a very wrong example, since it could be understood as suggestion to target all DIVs. Actually it broke the code of the question author. 
Now that you updated showing it's aplication, I upvoted ;)

Comment: @Krzysztof Trzos i don't want a scroll i want that image should adjust itself in a way that the text and box containing the text comes within it

Comment: @roy adjusting vertically?

Comment: @Krzysztof Trzos yes, the width of the image should cover the whole screen (leaving some margin on left and right side ) and then its height should adjust acc to the box and text within box, but there should b some margin between the image border and box border

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your comment div :

```
.wrap-text {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: did u meant comment01 class, i added to it but it had no effect

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use a vertical scroll:

**CSS:**

```
.comment01 {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    /*height: auto;*/ /* Deleted this */
    margin-top: -600px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-right: 25%;  
    height: 102px; /* Added this */
    overflow: auto; /* Added this */
}
```

[**Example demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/mcm16apa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```css
.box{
  padding:50px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  width:300px;
 
  text-align:center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>This is my text in the box</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

Answer (score 0):

Setting background-size: 100% auto; will cause the image to scale as far as it can in the x-axis. and then will make the image scale so the text is always within the image borders.

```css
.kitten {
  background: url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9gus8QYjY1rw0ggfo3_r5_400.gif) no-repeat;
  width: 80vw;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: pink;
}
.kitten span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="kitten">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried your code, but wasn't able to give margin between the text and image border. i would like to place margin on all 4 sides and then place a box and some text within it

Comment: Then add a `padding` to `.kitten` and make the `span` a block element and style it as you wish. (https://jsfiddle.net/800fL8wh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it will be helpful as per your requirement

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%; margin:0; padding:0px; display:block;
}
.image-container{
  width:100%;
  background:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ucSnMnlAKMY/VRD5Lk0e7II/AAAAAAAAAmQ/wUxuXmE00g4/w640-h480-no/Funny%2BAngry%2BBirds_38.jpg) center top no-repeat #d1d1d1 fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%
}
.image-caption{
  width:250px;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding:20px;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image-caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this is almost what i need but in your example the black box is attached to the image border, i wish to give some margin at top and bottom, i tried doind so by margin-top and margin-bottom but it moves the image also can u please tell how to do so

Comment: Add Padding in background container instead of adding margin to caption. Like below example

Answer (score 0):

Add Padding in background container instead of adding margin to caption. Like below example

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%; margin:0; padding:0px; display:block;
}
.image-container{
  width:100%;
  background:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ucSnMnlAKMY/VRD5Lk0e7II/AAAAAAAAAmQ/wUxuXmE00g4/w640-h480-no/Funny%2BAngry%2BBirds_38.jpg) center top no-repeat #d1d1d1 fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  padding:20px 0;
  height:100%
}
.image-caption{
  width:250px;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding:20px;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image-caption">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```